# why super() in Java

Tags: java, super

I am new to Java.Can someone please explain me this code?

```
abstract class Person {

private String name;
private String gender;

public Person(String nm, String gen){
    this.name=nm;
    this.gender=gen;
}

//abstract method
public abstract void work();

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Name="+this.name+"::Gender="+this.gender;
}

public void changeName(String newName) {
    this.name = newName;
}   
}

class Employee extends Person {

private int empId;

public Employee(String nm, String gen, int id) {
    super(nm, gen);
    this.empId=id;
}

@Override
public void work() {
    if(empId == 0){
        System.out.println("Not working");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Working as employee!!");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    //coding in terms of abstract classes
    Person student = new Employee("Dove","Female",0);
    Person employee = new Employee("Pankaj","Male",123);
    student.work();
    employee.work();
    //using method implemented in abstract class - inheritance
    employee.changeName("Pankaj Kumar");
    System.out.println(employee.toString());
}

}
```

*Here, why we use **super()**?* I know that *super()* is used to call the base class' constructor ! But I am not fully aware of this! How the name and gender values are assigned to the constructor *'Person()'* using *super()* .Can anybody explain this for me?

Comment: Also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 1):

Super () is used to call parent class constructor ...as the class may contain any numbers of constructors and these constructors are classified by the arguments passed to `super()` method....and yes it brings all types of variables to this current class constructor to use . Hope u got it .